# How to Format JSON correctly Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

i'm trying to load events into a calendar.

Therefore i need to make a JSONstring with the event data but i can't figure out how to do this.

how i create the data:

```
$tickets = Ticket::where('mechanic_id', $request->mechanic_id)->get();

$tickets_json[] = [];

foreach($tickets as $ticket) {
    $tickets_json['title'] = $ticket->number;
    $tickets_json['start'] = $ticket->planned_timestamp_start->format('d-m-Y H:i');
    $tickets_json['end'] = $ticket->planned_timestamp_end->format('d-m-Y H:i');
    $tickets_json['url'] = '/tickets/' . $ticket->id;
}
```

This returns:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => []
  "title" => "452"
  "start" => "27-10-2017 09:00"
  "end" => "27-10-2017 12:00"
  "url" => "/tickets/2"
]
```

This is not what i want and need.

I need it like this :

```
{
title: '63782136',
start: '27-10-2017 09:00',
end: '"27-10-2017 12:00"',
url: '/tickets/2'
},  
{
title: '23123',
start: '27-10-2017 09:00',
end: '"27-10-2017 12:00"',
url: '/tickets/3'
},  
{
title: '432512',
start: '27-10-2017 09:00',
end: '"27-10-2017 12:00"',
url: '/tickets/4'
},
```

I have tried:

`return response()->json($tickets_json);`

But doesn't return the correct format:

```
#data: "{"0":[],"title":"452","start":"27-10-2017 09:00","end":"27-10-2017 12:00","url":"\/tickets\/2"}"
```

It adds {"0":[],}
.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `$tickets_json[] = [];` to `$tickets_json = [];`.

Comment: But i need multiple tickets in 1 array

Comment: just return $tickets? If you would make a get request it will convert the data into a json array by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making the mistake of assigning your data to the first dimension of the array when you want it in the second dimension. The following should do the trick:

```
$tickets_json = [];

$tickets->each(function ($ticket) use (&$tickets_json) {
    $tickets_json[] = [
        'title' => $ticket->numer,
        'start' => $ticket->planned_timestamp_start->format('d-m-Y H:i'),
        'end' => $ticket->planned_timestamp_end->format('d-m-Y H:i'),
        'url' => '/tickets/' . $ticket->id
    ];
});

return $tickets_json;
```

This code will give you a proper formatted array which you can use to get the following JSON output:

```
[
    {
        "title": "63782136",
        "start": "27-10-2017 09:00",
        "end": "27-10-2017 12:00",
        "url": "/tickets/2"
    },  
    {
        "title": "23123",
        "start": "27-10-2017 09:00",
        "end": "27-10-2017 12:00",
        "url": "/tickets/3"
    }
]
```

Comment: My god, exactly what i needed. Much Thanks will approve answer when the approve-limit allows.